# Google analytics not showing for windows 8.1 universal apps

Tags: google-analytics, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, windows-8.1-universal

I am working with windows 10 universal apps and added a third party Google Analytics SDK, I am using the code below for page view.

```
GoogleAnalytics.EasyTracker.GetTracker().SendView("MainPage");
```

I added track id in Analytics.XML File, but the Analytics not working, I am also tried in windows 10 universal apps it is not working, and I get the code from [this zip file](http://www.windowsapptutorials.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Google-analytics.zip)

Nuget Package

[Google Analytics SDK for Windows and... 1.3.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GoogleAnalyticsSDK)

Project home

[Google Analytics SDK for Windows and Windows Phone](http://googleanalyticssdk.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Mind linking exactly what tracker you are using.  There is no official Google Analytics SDK for windows.

Comment: @DaImTo I get the SDk from https://www.nuget.org/packages/GoogleAnalyticsSDK

Comment: I would contact the developer of the third party SDK.  http://googleanalyticssdk.codeplex.com  but it hasn't been updated in a year.

Comment: so you are saying that Google Analytics is not worked for windows, right..?

Comment: Have you considered using [Hockey](https://www.hockeyapp.net/) instead?